# Annoying find operation running unasked in background

Tags: 16.04, indexing, core-apps

there is since recent updates a process ruining my hard discs, every day now at least once and for really long:

```
su nobody -s /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/find / -ignore_readdir_race      \( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o -fstype afs -o -fstype binfmt_misc -o -fstype proc -o -fstype smbfs -o -fstype autofs -o -fstype iso9660 -o -fstype ncpfs -o -fstype coda -o -fstype devpts -o -fstype ftpfs -o -fstype devfs -o -fstype mfs -o -fstype shfs -o -fstype sysfs -o -fstype cifs -o -fstype lustre_lite -o -fstype tmpfs -o -fstype usbfs -o -fstype udf -o -fstype ocfs2 -o      -type d -regex '\(^/tmp$\)\|\(^/usr/tmp$\)\|\(^/var/tmp$\)\|\(^/afs$\)\|\(^/amd$\)\|\(^/alex$\)\|\(^/var/spool$\)\|\(^/sfs$\)\|\(^/media$\)\|\(^/var/lib/schroot/mount$\)' \) -prune -o -print0
```

Does some knows where it comes from ? I already disabled anything else but this one puzzles me.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange processes on Server consume CPU](http://serverfault.com/questions/437218/strange-processes-on-server-consume-cpu)

Answer (score 0):

The process seems to be related mlocate, locate or update.db cron tasks.

It seems enough to delete all that jobs in /etc/cron.daily.